# poetry add legacy requirement

Tags: python, python-polars, python-poetry, legacy

I'm confronted to the legacy problem with polars. You can find that there are (at least) two versions of polars:

- [polars](https://pypi.org/project/polars/)
- [polars-lts-cpu](https://pypi.org/project/polars-lts-cpu/)

The second version is a legacy release, as this is displayed in the readme:

> Do you want polars to run on an old CPU (e.g. dating from before 2011)? Install pip install polars-lts-cpu. This polars project is compiled without avx target features.

Do note that both modules are "called" polars. I mean by that, that both are imported by running `import polars`: installing both at the same time could cause trouble.

**Question is, how do you implement your requirements for a new package?**

I see two ways of proceeding:

- one is (evidently) to release two versions of your own package, with two different requirements;
- the other would make use of the extras requirements (and I'm in no way sure this could work).

When trying the extras dependencies' declaration, I ended up with this in pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
polars = { version = "^0.18.5", optional = true }
polars-lts-cpu = { version = "^0.18.5", optional = true }

[tool.poetry.extras]
standard = ["polars"]
legacy = ["polars-lts-cpu"]
```

1. Is this valid ? *(I'm not 100% sure as I can't install polars-lts-cpu on my machine and check it, but this is unrelated)*;
2. If I release the package, but someone blunders the installation using a `pip install my_package --all-extras`:

- which polars will he/she end up with?
- does the order of dependencies in pyproject matters?
- if order matters, can I set "polars" in `tool.poetry.dependencies` while keeping polars-lts-cpu as optional (and thus "overwrite" polars when calling `pip install my_package[legacy]`)?

3. Can you prevent the `--all-extras` altogether?

Comment: I'm not aware of any better way to do what you're doing, neither with Poetry nor any other tool. Note, however, that `pip install` doesn't have an `--all-extras` option (though Poetry does) and end users will need to run either `pip install mypackage[standard]` or `pip install mypackage[legacy]`. They will have a broken install if all they do is `pip install mypackage`. I think that simply requires good documentation, though. I don't think there's a way to have one package overwrite another with the standard tooling.